# Install C# Service on Windows Server (Access Denied)

Tags: c#, service

I created a C# service. Now I want to install that service on Windows Server 2008 R2.
I am using the **InstallUtil** command to install the service. I opened the command prompt as an admin.

The service should run as a certain user, therefore I set the account to user on the Service Installer.

When I run the command I get an error:

An exception occured during the Install phase:
`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied`.

Here is the log file:

```
Installing assembly 'C:\Service\MyService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = C:\Service\MyService.InstallLog
   assemblypath = C:\Service\MyService.exe
Rolling back assembly 'C:\Service\MyService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole = 
   logfile = C:\Service\MyService.InstallLog
   assemblypath = C:\Service\MyService.exe
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller installer.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This exception will be     ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete.
```

Here is what is displayed on the command prompt:

```
Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\Service\MyService.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\Service\MyService.InstallLog.
Installing assembly 'C:\Service\MyService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   logfile = C:\Service\MyService.InstallLog
   assemblypath = C:\Service\MyService.exe

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access Denied
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller.OpenSecurityPolicy()
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.AssemblyInstaller.Install(IDictionary savedState)
   at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
   at System.Configuration.Install.TransactedInstaller.Install(IDictionary savedState)

The Rollback phase of the installation is beginning.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\Service\MyService.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\Service\MyService.InstallLog.
Rolling back assembly 'C:\Service\MyService.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   logfile = C:\Service\MyService.InstallLog
   assemblypath = C:\Service\MyService.exe
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.ServiceProcess.Ser
viceProcessInstaller installer.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an obj
ect.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might not fully revert to its initial state after the rollback is complete.

The Rollback phase completed successfully.

The transacted install has completed.
The installation failed, and the rollback has been performed.
```

Does somebody know what I need to do to install the service?

Comment: do you have custom code in isntaller?

Comment: There is no custom code in the installer.

Comment: I have now created a new empty service project in Visual Studio and tried to install that service on the server. I got the same error.

Comment: Did you start up command prompt with elevated permissions? The `Run as Admin` option when you right click it.

Comment: Yes I opened the command prompt with elevated permissions.

Comment: Perhaps I need some rights to install a service. When I try to install the service as a local system then I get an error that I have no right to access event logs. How would I set that right?

Comment: which .net is it? is it .net 4?

Comment: What is your environment? Are you on the domain? Is the service account in the local admin group? Sometimes, and this happes on our networks, the elevated accounts don't neccessarily have all the rights on the local system.

Comment: I think you can try `InstallUtil /LogFile=[filename] "exe path"`. Do not use arbitrary params as you can set those in the services.msc afterwards.

Comment: Check the Project Settings and see if you are building it on "Any CPU".

Comment: Just Run as Administrator your cmd.exe. This simple tip helped me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally could install the service. I was logged into the server in a role called server admin. My Administrator added my account to the local administrators group of the server. After this I could install the service. It seams like the server Admin account, that I used to log into the system did not have full admin priviledges.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You really didn't give any details as to what your service does and I am unable to comment direct on your post yet but you might try [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/b5321bf3-cbc2-4361-adf2-8f3a50002217/)

The summary of this is to check and make sure you are running the proper 32/64 bit installutil.exe and to verify your merge module are not causing the issue.

Perhaps a better description of your service would help? Does the service install fine on your local machine as opposed to the server?

Answer (score 1):

This Problem is due to Security, Better open Command prompt in RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR and install your Service, it fix your problem surely

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it will be resolved in two steps:

1. At first, Copy/Paste the `DEBUG` folder of your project file—this will be available in `/bin`—into some other folder (say, `D:\Debug`)
2. Run the below command at the CMD prompt:

   ```
   cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
   ```
3. Finally, create the service using:

   ```
   sc create "ServiceName" binpath="D:\P1\Debug\ServiceName.exe"
   ```